# Multiple Express routers

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've always used `express.Router()` as as way to prefix routes for an API. For example:

```
var app = express(),
    api = express.Router();

app.use("/api", api);
```

Now I can do this:

```
api.post("/contact", function(req, res){
  //process contact
});
```

But now I want more than 1 of these routes. For example I would do this:

```
var app = express(),
    api = express.Router(),
    auth = express.Router();

app.use("/api", api);
app.use("/auth", auth);
```

Unfortunately this does not work. If I do a call to `/auth/login` from my Angular frontend, it comes through as `/api/auth/login`.

How can I use multiple routers like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited: Maybe this is what you're looking for?

```
var app = express();

var api = express.Router()
    .get('/contact', contacts.get);

var auth = express.Router()
    .get('/login', login);

app.use('/api', api);
app.use('/auth', auth);
```

Comment: I want the `api` and `auth ` routes to be separate. So requests will come in at `/api/contact` or `/auth/login`. At the moment, the 2 routes seem to conflict with each other. So in my Angular code I do: `$http.post("/auth/login")` and in Node it routes it as `/api/auth/login` which is incorrect

Comment: I don't see the conflict, unless you've defined an `/auth/login` route on your `api` router, which belongs on the `api` router instead. I've edited my answer, but if that's no good, can you update your question with more details as to what specifically you want routed to which methods?

Comment: Ah I think it was an issue with my Angular code actually! Yes you're code above works, thank you.

Comment: Great! Can you elaborate on what your angular issue was? You might even post it as your own answer and mark that as the answer instead of mine (though I do appreciate the upvote) That way other SO users will get some use out of this question :)

Comment: It was stupid, I was making the http request in Angular to `/api/auth/login`. I don't know why.